# React Native manipulate values between components

Tags: react-native

I have this Modal component:

```
    export default class PopUpModal extends Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      //this.state = {windowVisible: false};
   }
   openModal = () => {
      this.props.onToggle(true);
   }
   closeModal = () => {
      console.log('Pressing CLOSE');
      this.props.onToggle(false);
   }
   setMessage = (text) => {
       this.props.modalText = text;
   }
   render() {

      return (

        <Modal style={styles.modal} position={"center"} swipeToClose={false} backdropPressToClose={false} visible={this.props.windowVisible} 
        onRequestClose={() => {this._setModalVisible(false)}} >
                <View style={styles.modalContentContainer}>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
                  this.closeModal();
                }}>

                <Text>{this.props.modalText}</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                </View>
            </Modal>
      );

   }
}
```

being rendered in a Scene. And I've manage to get actions to work between the two, with the "setModalVisible" e.i. But I want to manipulate/change the value of `this.props.modalText`in the Scene since it will display error messages which may vary.

This is the relevant code from the Scene:

```
    export default class LoginScene extends Component {

  constructor(p) {
    super(p);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      windowVisible: false,
      modalText: '',
    };

  }
    onTogglePopUpWindow =(value) => {
    console.log('PRESSING UP');
    this.setState({windowVisible: value});
  }

  render() {

    const { email, password } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>


        {this.state.windowVisible ? <PopUpModal
          windowVisible={this.state.windowVisible} 
          onToggle={this.onTogglePopUpWindow}
        /> : null}
```

So there's really no code on the matter to point at since I'm not even sure how to begin. But what I want to achieve is to have the `<Text>` element's value in my PopUpModal component to change depending on some if statements I'll write. Basically setting it's value from the `LogInScene` .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure did I understand your need correctly or not. It seems you want to pass data from LoginScene which is modalText to the PopUpModal component.

You can pass it as a props.

```
<PopUpModal
    windowVisible={this.state.windowVisible} 
    onToggle={this.onTogglePopUpWindow}
    modalText={this.state.modalText}      
        />
```

Then in PopUpModal component you will have access to this modal text.

```
export default class PopUpModal extends Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      console.log(this.props.modalText)
   }
```

Comment: So simple.. Didn't see the relationship Modal had with Text like that. Thank you!